# Notepad++ Regex miss numbers only in replacement

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm reasonably new to Notepad++ and regular expressions, I'm really struggling to solve this issue

```
0:6[105][56]
0:6[105][55]
0:6[105][54]
0:6[104][53]
```

?:?[??][??] -> where numbers can be anything

I've tried using the Find:

- Find (:)|(])
- Replace (][)|(->connectedwaypoints.push_back)

This doesn't seem to work

below is my desired result.

```
WarpPoints[0]->paths_connected[6]->connectedwaypoints.push_back(HiFiWaypoints[105][56]);


WarpPoints[?]->paths_connected[?]->connectedwaypoints.push_back(HiFiWaypoints[?][?]);
```

? can be any given number, I want to not replace the numbers, but everything else.

Comment: @McDonald's my expected format / outcome is WarpPoints[0]->paths_connected[6]->connectedwaypoints.push_back(HiFiWaypoints[105][56]);

Comment: @McDonald's Thats ok, do you have any idea how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find:

```
([0-9]):([0-9])(\[[0-9]+\]\[[0-9]+\])
```

And replace with

```
WarpPoints[\1]->paths_connected[\2]->connectedwaypoints.push_back\(HiFiWaypoints\3\)\;
```

And the search mode should be "Regular expression".

Explained:

- For the find part, `[0-9]` means any digits, `\[` and `\]` means to match any `[` and `]` respectively.  `(` and `)` will make anything inside the parenthesis referred in "replace with " as `\1` `\2` etc.
- For the replace with part, it is pretty self-explanatory, where `\1` is the contents within the first pair of parenthesis, `\2` being the contents within the second pair, etc.

Please Google on "regular expression" if you are not sure what the other symbols means.

Comment: That worked thanks! I was trying to do it bit by bit, and was taking a long time forgot \ is often used in many languages to \[ use symbols, thats where I was going wrong.